# Cassandra Error Too many pending remote requests

Tags: cassandra

Nodes will frequently be marked down with the following message:

```
ERROR [MessagingService-Incoming-/192.168.1.34] 2019-09-12 10:52:54,054  MessagingService.java:823 - java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException while receiving WRITES.WRITE from /192.168.1.34, caused by: Too many pending remote requests!
```

I have tried narrowing the problem down and I think its memtable related.
Because when I run a nodetool tpstats it shows TPC/all/WRITE_MEMTABLE_FULL having approx 4000 active. 
Looking through opscenter graphs I can see 
that TP: Write Memtable Full Active is at approx 4000 and TP: Gossip Tasks Pending keeps increasing and OS: CPU User sits at 80%.
I have also noticed commit log directory exceeds what we set of 16GB and have seen a node with 7911 files(248GB)

The nodes were previously set to have
cassandra-env.sh

```
MAX_HEAP_SIZE="64G"
HEAP_NEWSIZE="16G"
```

cassandra.yaml

```
commitlog_segment_size_in_mb: 32
memtable_heap_space_in_mb: 4096
memtable_offheap_space_in_mb: 4096
memtable_cleanup_threshold: 0.5
commitlog_total_space_in_mb: 16384
memtable_flush_writers: 2
```

I am currently trying to use these new settings on one of the nodes to see if it fixes the servers performance

```
memtable_heap_space_in_mb: 10240
memtable_offheap_space_in_mb: 2048
memtable_cleanup_threshold: 0.11
memtable_flush_writers: 8
```

If anyone has any ideas on what else I can look at. 
Also how do I view MemtablePool.BlockedOnAllocation metric that it details against the memtable_flush_writers section in http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/configuration/cassandra_config_file.html

Comment: you can go to community.datastax.com for questions about DSE. What was a reason for selection of heap size so big?

Comment: Thought if i gave it a larger size it would have more breathing room before it ever can reach max mem table heap space. I wasn't having any luck with that so its now 16gb heap space and 0.8 cleanup threshold. So it creates less sstables and does big cleanouts. I think its helping but it looks like its still got too many commit logs.

Comment: 16 or 24Gb is ok for pure Cassandra workloads. Regarding cleanup threshold - it's better to regulate via `memtable_flush_writers`...

Comment: How high can you set the memtable_flush_writers. As with current settings its not managing to keep commitlog directory down. Are you in the communtiy.datastax.com(is this a website?) or cassandra slack? Cant seem to paste anything with newlines in this chat its annoying.

Comment: number of flush writers depends on the type of disks that you have. also, you need to set either `memtable_cleanup_threshold`, or `memtable_flush_writers` - first is calculated from 2nd

Comment: Currently using SSD but commitlogs and sstables are on same drive. Is it ideal to then split these 2 to different drives and up the flush writers to maybe 12 or 16? As for memtable cleanup threshold i know it says to use 1/(writers+1). Which is why with 8 Writers i had it set to 0.11. However the commitlog directory was still greatly exceeding its total space as well as creating lots of sstables and with 8 compactors it wasn't keeping up with the workload.

Comment: you can try with 2 or 4 flush writers for example. same disk for data & commit log isn't so bad for SSD. if the compactors doesn't cope with traffic, then you may need to increase compaction throughput, etc. But it's really requires more detailed analysis of the logs, etc.

Comment: It seems to have stabilized a little with 8 writers, 32gb commit dir, 16gb memtable heap, 0.05 memtable cleanup threshold. But i still see the problem where commitlog directory exceeds the 32gb limit and keeps climbing. Its at around 53gb-79gb approx each node. Is there a bug in DSE6.0.2, CQL3.5.4?

Comment: I recommend to get from 6.0.2 to latest 6.0 or 6.7 - 6.0.2 is quite buggy. Also you need to use either `memtable_flush_writers` or cleanup threshold

Comment: Ahhh so you are saying don't set both memtable_flush_writers & memtable_cleanup_threshold. Just set one of these options and leave the other on what it configures automatically which is 1/(memtable_flush_writers+1) for memtable_cleanup_threshold. As for upgrading i'll see if I can get approval to upgrade our dev/test/prod clusters.

Comment: Memtable cleanup threshold is calculated automatically from flush writers